# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, postgresql

I am developing a web app that uses angularjs, nodejs, and postgresql. I have two tables in my database, one for inventory and the other for client. I combined my index.js files, in my routes folder, in which both tables have a findAll function. When I put the two references for the tables in the index.js, only one works at a time. Here is the template that both tables use that includes findAll:

```
exports.getobjects = function(req, res) {
models.Object.findAll().then(function(objectss){
    res.json(objects);
});
};
```

Has anyone done what I am trying to do?
UPDATE: Here is entire index.js file :

```
/*
* GET home page.
*/

var models = require("../models");

exports.index = function(req, res) {
res.render('index', {
    title : 'title'
 });
 };
 /* clients */
 exports.getclients = function(req, res) {
 models.Client.findAll().then(function(clients){
    res.json(clients);
});
};

exports.saveclients = function(req, res) {
models.Client.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    ssn: req.body.ssn,
    dln: req.body.dln,
    dls: req.body.dls,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    email: req.body.email,
    notes: req.body.notes,     
}).then(function(clients){
    res.json(clients.dataValues);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("ops: " + error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'error' });
});
};

/*inventory*/
exports.getunits = function(req, res) {
models.Unit.findAll().then(function(units){
    res.json(units);

});
};

exports.saveunits = function(req, res) {
models.Unit.create({
    name: req.body.text,
    quant: reg.body.quant                        
}).then(function(units){
    res.json(units.dataValues);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("ops: " + error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'error' });
});
};
```

Comment: can you include the index.js code? One thing I have picked up is that the objectss (2 ss) is being passed into the callback method but you are accessing objects (1 s) which will not be defined

Comment: sorry that is a typo here, not in my code ! I will post index.js though

Comment: your export syntax is actually just fine. `module` is global, doing `exports.foo = function() {}` is valid. that said, from your repro code it's totally unclear what's failing. can you reduce the repro down to just a few lines and post the actual error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing your exports incorrectly. Here is an example of how to do it correctly.

Lets say I want to export 2 functions for a module this is a simple way to achieve it.

myModule.js

```
module.exports = {
    awesomeMethod: function () {

    },
    coolMethod: function () {

    }
}
```

Now to use it I would do the following

var myModule = require('./myModule');

```
myModule.awesomeMethod();
myModule.coolMethod();
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried to implement this into my index.js and now I get a syntaxerror stating that   clientMethod= function () {  is an invalid shorthand property  initializer

Comment: it should be clientMethod: function () . Replace the = with :

Comment: I see, I have tried this as well and I get the error: function() is an unexpected token, where there is an up arrow below the first (